# Como salvar o título de um post com base em um campo selecionado?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-types

O meu problema é o seguinte, criei um custom post type chamado "Destaques da Home" e dentro dele o usuário vai adicionando o post que deseja, esses posts vem de um **select_advanced** do **Metabox**, fiz uma função para passar o post selecionado para o título do post atual, porém ele acaba retornando um número não sei porque.

Segue a minha função e alguns prints para ajudar no entendimento:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'teste', 10, 2 );
function teste( $title, $post_id )
{
    if( $new_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'id_do_metabox', true ) )
    {
        return $new_title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o select funciona mostrando um par de **chave e valor**. O que você está vendo e selecionando no select é apenas um label, o que está sendo salvo no banco é o **ID** do post e não o título, assim você precisa buscar o título do ID do post. Ficando o código assim:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'teste', 10, 2 );
function teste( $title, $post_id )
{
    if( $new_title_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'id_do_metabox', true ) )
    {
        return get_the_title($new_title_id);
    }
    return $title;
}
```